# Count how many times strings from one data frame appear to another data frame in R dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr

I have two data frames that look like this:

```r
df1 <- data.frame(reference=c("cat","dog"))
print(df1)
#>   reference
#> 1       cat
#> 2       dog
df2 <- data.frame(data=c("cat","car","catt","cart","dog","dog","pitbull"))
print(df2)
#>      data
#> 1     cat
#> 2     car
#> 3    catt
#> 4    cart
#> 5     dog
#> 6     dog
#> 7 pitbull
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

I want to find how many times the words cat and dog from the df1 exist in df2.
I want my data to look like this

```
animals   n
cat       1
dog       2
```

Any help or guidance is appreciated. My reference list is huge. I tried to grep each one of them but ll take me time.

Thank you for your time. Happy holidays

Comment: Re: "I tried to grep each one" - you need grep and regex when you are doing pattern matching or partial string matching.  When you are matching whole exact strings as you are here, you just need `==` or `%in%` or other non-regex functions (as all the answers here illustrate).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A possible solution, `tidyverse`-based:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- data.frame(reference=c("cat","dog"))
df2 <- data.frame(data=c("cat","car","catt","cart","dog","dog","pitbull"))

df1 %>% 
  group_by(animal = reference) %>% 
  summarise(n = sum(reference == df2$data), .groups = "drop")

#> # A tibble: 2 × 2
#>   animal     n
#>   <chr>  <int>
#> 1 cat        1
#> 2 dog        2
```

Answer (score 6):

Update: Thanks to Gregor Thomas:

```
library(dplyr)

left_join(df1,df2, by=c("reference"="data")) %>% 
  count(reference)
```

output:

```
  reference n
1       cat 1
2       dog 2
```

We could use `semi_join` and then `count`:

```
library(dplyr)

semi_join(df2,df1, by=c("data"="reference")) %>% 
  count(data)
```

```
  data n
1  cat 1
2  dog 2
```

Comment: I would stick with a `left_join(df1, df2)` unless OP clearly specifies that they want to omit `reference` rows with 0 counts.

Comment: Thanks Gregor Thomas. Will update.

Answer (score 4):

It may be faster with a join

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df2)[, .(animals = data)][df1, .(n = .N), 
     on = .(animals = reference), by = .EACHI]
   animals n
1:     cat 1
2:     dog 2
```

---

Or use `table` after `subset`ing the data in `base R`

```
table(subset(df2, data %in% df1$reference, select = data))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a third option:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- tibble(reference=c("cat","dog"))
df2 <- tibble(data=c("cat","car","catt","cart","dog","dog","pitbull"))

df2 |>
  count(data) |>
  filter(data %in% df1$reference) |>
  rename(animal = data)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   animal     n
#>   <chr>  <int>
#> 1 cat        1
#> 2 dog        2
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `str_count` with the column in the second df collapsed into one string.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df1 %>%
  transmute(animals = reference, n = str_c(df2$data, collapse = " ") %>%
    str_count(str_c("\\b", reference, "\\b")) )
#>   animals n
#> 1     cat 1
#> 2     dog 2
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

```
df1$n <- colSums(outer(df2$data, df1$reference, '=='))

df1
#>   reference n
#> 1       cat 1
#> 2       dog 2
```

Comment: wow a very nice nice one. Thank you, its impressive